# Массив forEach правильная передача аргументов

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, вот хочу увеличить значения в массиве на 1. Соответственно создаю массив, через foreach пробегаюсь по нему, и закидываю это в функцию. и Тут вопрос - 
вот вы видите первый вариант, он рабочий

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
data.forEach(function(z, x, c) { c[x] = z + 2; });
alert(data);
```

А вот второй нет (поменял местами аргументы в ф-ции)

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
data.forEach(function(c, x, z) { c[x] = z + 2; });
alert(data);
```

Собственно вопрос - почему если поменять аргументы в ф-ции местами, то ф-ция перестаёт работать?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, может потому что данные ассоциируются с переменными по их индексу в определении функции, а не по именам? Если ты заменил их в определении - поменяй и в самой функции `z[x] = c + 2;`

Comment: Может быть...не знал такого

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, порядок аргументов в callback: 

1. Текущий обрабатываемый элемент в массиве.
2. Индекс текущего обрабатываемого элемента в массиве.
3. Массив, по которому осуществляется проход.

Вот и получается, что во втором варианте, вы берете текущий элемент "**c**", в котором, как в массиве, пытаетесь найти элемент с индексом "**x**" и присвоить значение суммы массива "**z**" и 2.

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, это я понял, я не могу найти, где про это почитать - не будет у вас ссылки?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, [тут][1] можно про это почитать

[1]:https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: > я не могу найти где про это почитать

когда люди пишут что-то подобное, становится любопытно  - черт возьми, как и чем вы ищете, что не можете найти таких элементарных вещей?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, ещё можно почитать [тут][1], этот учебник рекомендовал бы вообще полностью прочитать

[1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration

Comment: @MasterAlex спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Более того, важен только порядок, а имена могут быть любые:

    var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    data.forEach(function(ДядяВася, ТетяФрося, ПростоЧтоТо) { ПростоЧтоТо[ТетяФрося] = ДядяВася + 2; });
    alert(data);

И да, этот код совершенно рабочий, даже с такими именами.

Comment: именуйте переменные нормально! а то устроились тут обфускаторами понимаешь...